# How to draw multiple 3d object on unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, camera, drawing

I want to draw a 3d circle and a 3d cube at center of circle on unity3d. I create 6 faces of a cube below code :

```
mesh.vertices = new Vector3[]{
        // face 1 (xy plane, z=0)
        new Vector3(0,0,0), 
        new Vector3(1,0,0), 
        new Vector3(1,1,0), 
        new Vector3(0,1,0), 
        // face 2 (zy plane, x=1)
        new Vector3(1,0,0), 
        new Vector3(1,0,1), 
        new Vector3(1,1,1), 
        new Vector3(1,1,0), 
        // face 3 (xy plane, z=1)
        new Vector3(1,0,1), 
        new Vector3(0,0,1), 
        new Vector3(0,1,1), 
        new Vector3(1,1,1), 
        // face 4 (zy plane, x=0)
        new Vector3(0,0,1), 
        new Vector3(0,0,0), 
        new Vector3(0,1,0), 
        new Vector3(0,1,1), 
        // face 5  (zx plane, y=1)
        new Vector3(0,1,0), 
        new Vector3(1,1,0), 
        new Vector3(1,1,1), 
        new Vector3(0,1,1), 
        // face 6 (zx plane, y=0)
        new Vector3(0,0,0), 
        new Vector3(0,0,1), 
        new Vector3(1,0,1), 
        new Vector3(1,0,0), 
    };
```

I create a circle around the cube below code :

```
float x;
    float y;
    float z = 0.5f;

    float angle = 1f;

    for (int i = 0; i < (segments + 1); i++)
    {
        x = 0.5f + Mathf.Sin (Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xradius;
        y = 0.5f + Mathf.Cos (Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yradius;

        line.SetPosition (i,new Vector3(x,y,z));

        angle += (360f / segments);
    }
```

I expect that upper codes do upper task. But they don't. I see a cube and circle. But the cube is not cenetr of circle 3d. z position is not right for me.

My screenshot is below :

[image]

Should I use multiple camera for this work?

Comment: Your code looks fine, at first glance. If anything, I'd mainly want to check the transform component on the cube and camera objects. Is either of them rotated in the scene?

Comment: They are rotated in the scene. But I think that x rotation of circle is not true. In upper image, angles of cube and circle don't look like same.

Comment: Points on a `Mesh` are in local space. Points on a `LineRenderer` are in world space. One will follow its transform, but the other will not. If needed, you can adjust this by calling `transform.TransformPoint` while assigning line points.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, answering here because I cannot comment yet. As rutter said, it looks like a space problem. But you CAN make the points of a `LineRenderer` operate in local space, just uncheck the `Use World Space` bool in the inspector. This will also let you move your `GameObject` around the scene freely.